# IE reloads page when opening F12 developer tools

Tags: internet-explorer, refresh, reload, ie-developer-tools

Recently I installed IE 11(previously IE 9) on my DEV Windows 7 machine. Whenever I press or open the F12 Developer tools, it reloads the page. Is there anyway to stop this behavior?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you go to the Emulation tool do you have any settings set? When F12 is opened with a persisted emulation setting such as document mode it has to reload that page to apply the setting. You can clear any settings with the `'Reset Emulation settings'` you can also turn off the behavior by disabling `'Persist Emulation settings'` within IE Developer Tools.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Disabling "Persist Emulation settings" fixed it :)

Comment: How to do this in chrome

Comment: I can't get to emulation tool settings because they are in devtools which closes immediately when opened because the page refreshes

Comment: The settings are persisted in a `settings.json` file in:
`C:\Users\%UserName%\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\F12\emulation`
and:
`C:\Users\%UserName%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\F12\emulation`

You should be able to delete those files to remove the persisted settings.