# IE 11 refresh ( F5) only work when developer tools (f12) opened

Tags: refresh, internet-explorer-11, browser-cache, reload, ie11-developer-tools

I have an web application and whenever i do some changes in server side and try to refresh the page from IE11, it does not work.
Only works when if I close all opened IE sessions and reopen new page or hit F12 Developer tools open.
Is there anyway to mimic this behavior programmatically? or any idea why only work when developer tools is opened?
It does work in Chrome or FireFox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE reloads page when opening F12 developer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31165927/ie-reloads-page-when-opening-f12-developer-tools)

Comment: i read that also but my requirement is different, i want to use that option programmatically in java.