# Webpage reloading when opening developer tools in MAC Chrome

Tags: javascript, web, developer-tools

I am noticing a new feature on websites, that whenever I open developer tools on a loaded webpage, the webpage also starts reloading. I am listing down the webpages, where I saw this behaviour

1. https://medium.com/
2. https://blog.logrocket.com/writing-readable-code-with-typescript-enums-a84864f340e9/
3. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/
4. https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/#naming--uppercase
5. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-to-capitalize-your-javascript-constants-4fabc0a4a4c4/
6. office365 outlook mail

List can be elongated, 

  1.  I thought it may be due to the `settings on networks panel, which is a checkbox to disable cache` but I tried toggling it, still page would reload.
2. I also tried resetting chrome developer tools settings and refreshing the browser, but still getting same behaviour

Anyone has any idea about possible cause, or is there something new trend which started in web industry?

Comment: Your question might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31165927/ie-reloads-page-when-opening-f12-developer-tools this behaviour might be browser dependent

Comment: Thank you for the link,     are you getting this behaviour?

Comment: I am definitely sure it is not a new trend or feature of browsers. I have many browsers installed and they are  all latest versions. I never experienced such thing. But seems like the link @canbax shared is the answer because it is kind of similar situation as yours